# How to change header and footer dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, css, frameworks

Good morning,

I'm creating my own framework to use in my PHP projects, and I was thinking of some way that I could add .CSS files in the header part of the page, and .JS files and scripts in the footer (keeping HTML clean and valid), but - all this dynamically.

I mean, for example, imagine I have the following structure:

1. index.php
2. components

   - component1

     - component1.php
     - component1.js
     - component1.css

I would like to include each file I need dynamically in index.php for example, keeping the code clean.

And for example, imagine that I insert JS directly in component1.php, is it possible to dynamically add it to component1.js (without human job, to save time in future)

Thanks.

Comment: shure, you can read the files in the directory and include them, however if you look at what other frameworks do, in component1.php they would register witch script and witch js files index.php should include

Comment: But how do they register it? For example, when you arrive the supposed part that "register" it, you can't change the HTML you have already generated.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, all your logic should be at the start, before you start generating / outputting html. There you decide what you need to include and then you include it at the appropriate place.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for Output Buffering? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: @jeroen but how could I send the information of the page I'm on and which files should be loaded, if that is defined in a view (or somethin' like that) after the header has been loaded?

Comment: @Ivo Pereira I have added an answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way of doing it would be to represent your entire template/view/whatever-you-want-to-call-it as an object:

```
class View {
    // ...
}
```

The `index.php` file could determine which component(s) to use, create them, and then poll them for any required CSS/JS files:

```
$view = new View();

foreach ($components as $component) {
    $cmp = new $component();
    $view->addCss($cmp->getCss());
    $view->addJs($cmp->getJs());
}
```

Once everything has been included and such, then `index.php` can just render the entire thing:

```
$view->render();
```

Obviously this is just an example, and your syntax will vary, but hopefully you get the idea.

**Edit:** You could also make the logic a little more brief by simply adding components to the view directly, and have the view's internal logic handle polling/adding the CSS/JS, rather than `index.php`.  Of course, it really depends on what a "component" is supposed to be in your framework, so I'll leave that up to you to decide.

Comment: And how you could say which view should be invoked? For example a switch case in the index.php, and then calling the class?

Comment: That's called _routing_, and in most frameworks, it's based on the URL.  For example, the URL `/products/view/123` would invoke the `viewAction()` method of the `ProductController`, and `/cars/index` would invoke the `indexAction()` method of the `CarController`.

Comment: you should look MVC architecture, that's what this type op framework is called. And it's really a very good way to build scalable, easy to maintain projects. Would be my choice if i where to write my own framework! +1 for the OOP approach!

Comment: And should I call for example a new view based on a switch case, where I choose the page I want to show?

Comment: @IvoPereira: No, you should do it dynamically based on the URL, like I explained in my last comment.  If `/products/index` is your URL, then you will have `$foo = "products"` and `$bar = "index"`, and you do something like `$controllerClass = ucfirst($foo) . 'Controller'; $controller = new $controllerClass(...); $action = $bar . 'Action'`, and then dispatch your request as `$controller->{$action}()`.  You can also check if `method_exists($controller, $action)` and give the user a 404 Not Found if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example of how to include your js and css assets at the top, before you start outputting anything:

```
// somewhere in the beginning, before html output
$js = array();
$css = array();

$css[] = 'all_pages.css';
$js[] = 'all_pages.js';
if (some_condition_based_on_page)
{
  $css[] = 'some_page_specific.css';
  $js[] = 'some_page_specific.js';
}

...

// in your view where you build the head section
foreach ($css as $item)
{
  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='{$item}' type='text/css'>";
}

...

// in your view where you build the footer
foreach ($js as $item)
{
  echo "<link src='{$item}' type='text/javascript'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and more portable way would be to include all files matching a certain pattern, e.g., /components/component1/header.css

This would present two complications. One is performance (you need to check all the directories of all your components). The other is isolation of components, i.e., what happens if you need a given CSS to be included before or after another which might or might not be there?

You might try to solve both problems by including a "manifest" in each component, which could specify, at first, the location of any files and where they should be included. Then your processing is reduced to examining the "components" directory and decoding all manifests, and "compiling" this in a series of directive vectors (e.g. $CSSToBeIncludedInThisOrder[] ). You might also serialize the compiled object to a cached file. Of course, any alterations to components should include removal of the compiled meta-manifest.

Later on, you might include in the manifest instruction such as conditional priorities.

All this should be done BEFORE anything is sent to the client's browser (what if component ZZZ wishes to alter the ob_ state, or maybe the encoding, or is a download override component and wants to send a Content-Type of application/octet-stream?), but the "compilation" should allow to keep perceptual latency low.

So let me clarify:

```
1. index.php checks whether a metamanifest.cache file exists.
2. If it does, it runs something like
    $__META = unserialize(file_get_contents($METACACHE));
   and goes on to #4.
3. If it does not, opendirs/readdirs the components directory,
   looks what files are there, decides (but does not do yet) what to do with them,
   placing those decisions in $__META, e.g. $__META['HeaderJS'][].
4. Now HTML generation begins: the __META array is walked and everything that
   needs doing gets done (headers, inclusion of JS in heads, etc.).
```

Phase #3 might even perform some duplicate checks or versioning, say you have two components that both need "jQuery.js" to be included; instead of blindly appending "/components/comp1/js/jQuery.js" and "/components/comp2/js/jQuery.js" to a __Meta['HeaderJS'], the system could declare a conflict or decide it is solved by including only one of them, thereby further reducing processing time.

Comment: Wow, this seems great, but I really need to study a little of metamanifest as sincerely, I've never know what they are. Gonna read a little about them, thanks!